# gsoap does not serve over both ipv4 and ipv6

Tags: c++, sockets, ipv6, ipv4, gsoap

I am trying to implement a gsoap server that listens same port over both ipv4 and ipv6, but it does not listed in "`netstat -l`" command as tcp6 although I compiled gsoap with `-DWITH_IPV6 -DWITH_NO_IPV6_V6ONLY` macro definitions."`netstat -l`" command has tcp listenning server. When I compile code with `-DWITH_IPV6  -DWITH_IPV6_V6ONLY` macros it works with only Ipv6 and "`netstat -l`" response has tcp6 listenning server.

When I debug [the code](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/stdsoap2.cpp) I saw that `soap_bind` function passes `ai_family = PF_UNSPEC` through `getaddrinfo`, and it does not use `ai_next` of returned addrinfo data. addrinfo.ai_family set to AF_INET, addrinfo.ai_next->ai_family set to AF_INET6 and it does not use `addrinfo.ai_next`.

Is there any way to succeed this with/out patching gsoap source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I research there is no possible way to bind and listen over two address family AF_INET and AF_INET6 using gsoap. To achieve my subject I made two soap object and bind over different sockets (one is ipv4, other is ipv6) using my modified soap_bind function.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this exact same issue.

Turns out it is supported.

Just define `WITH_NO_IPV6_V6ONLY`. (Which results in `WITH_IPV6` being defined stdsoap2.h)

That results in setting an option on the socket that allows a dual-stack socket. As far as I can see, depending on the system that may be the default. It's not under Windows and you'll need Vista or greater for dual stack support.